# Google slides API provide the wrong width and Height measurement value in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, fabric, google-slides, google-slides-api, fabricjs2

I am creating a tool that converts Google Slides presentations into FabricJS elements using the Google Slides API. For reference, [Click here](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/get). Now, we are getting all the element's sizes object widths, and heights the same value instead of the original available on Google Slides. I have attached the screenshot for reference, Please provide me the solution to How can, I get the original value from API. [image: For the reference]

Comment: I have a documentation here that you can use to understand sizing and shaping on Google Slide https://developers.google.com/slides/api/guides/transform. On your question I am trying to identify what you mean about the original value you are referring about but I am assuming that it is about the magnitude which does not refer to the size. Please read over this concept as well to better understand about Google Slide API https://developers.google.com/slides/api/concepts/page-elements